# Gitlab-ci & Terraform, create environment for the lifetime of the MR

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

How can I create a test environment that lives the lifetime of the Merge request,

New MR created -> run Terraform job (Once) -> apply and test changes ... -> once issue fixed destroy the env the moment of the Merge.

As terraform is idempotent we can rerun the plan/apply without issues, but how to manage the destroy part ?

I tried to use variables like `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROUVED` to run the job after the MR is approved but I didn't had much luck , the variable is empty (even after approval)

Comment: Personally, I would just run a scheduled job that performs the cleanup, unless the couple extra hours of running makes a significant difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab has a builtin feature to [stop an environment when a merge request is merged or closed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment-when-a-merge-request-is-merged-or-closed). This is documented in the context of the so-named "[review apps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/)" strategy -- which involves the deployment of temporary dynamic environments which are destroyed automatically after they are no longer needed.

All you need to do is make sure you're defining the [`environment:on_stop` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#environmenton_stop) for your deployment job, which lets you specify a job that will be automatically run when an associated MR is closed. Then define the job with a script that will destroy the environment (e.g., call `tf destroy`) that has the `environment:action:` defined as `stop`.

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy
  - teardown

deploy_review_environment:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    # trigger on_stop job when MR is closed/merged
    on_stop: teardown_review_environment
  script:
    - tf apply # or whatever
  # ...

teardown_review_environment:
  stage: teardown
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
  script:
    - tf destroy # or whatever
  when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
```

The use of `GIT_STRATEGY: none` is important in case you delete the branch before the environment should be torn down (for example, if you check the "delete source branch" button when merging an MR).